# Find script responsible for opening a new window

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, dom

I have a website that that suddenly start triggering a new ad window, something that I didn't do myself. I want to know how can I know which part of the page or script is responsible for opening the new window after I click a specific link?

There are a lot of files, so I am searching for a tool that can catch those specific javascript codes that do pop ups. Then I can find the source of the code and neutralize it. I prefer not to do manual search because there are a lot of JS files.

Comment: without much to info to go on start in network tab of browser console and see what scripts are loaded and where they come from. Then sniff out window methods in ones you aren't familiar with. If necessary there are javascript beatifier sites to de-minify scripts also to make them more readable

Comment: Already did that, couldn't find any specific original that look suspected.

Comment: Consider a Firefox plugin called "NoScript". It allows you to selectively enable and disable scripts by source. Play until you know which site is loading the offending script, then find the script(s) and analyse them. Difficult to find `window.open` in a minified script if it's been deliberately obfuscated.

Comment: well you gave next to no detail about what you had tried so far. In firebug can search files... have you tried that

Comment: There are a lot of files, and I prefer a tool to help me with that job. [update the question as you said]

Comment: Why not start with looking at what JS is executed when you click the link? Simply use any browser, press F12 and select the link and trace it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE press f12 and start the profiler. It will tell you what javascript has executed so far during your browsing session. I would look at the calls there to narrow it down.

Comment: check it, but it seems that it happens in firefox and chrome, not internet explorer. The bad guy probably knew about the IE tool :[   Any way to do the same on chrome?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
window.open()
```

In JavaScript

Comment: I actually search for a tool to help me out, there are a lot of extenal JS files, hard go over all of them